# clearTimeout doesn't clear it everytime

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout, cleartimeout

I'm trying to build a `carousel` that:

- Has an auto-timer ( every X seconds )
- Has directional arrows ( that when used, should reset the auto-timer to X seconds again )

I had this using the setInterval function but the problem was even worse, so I decided to change it for setTimeout and call it recursively.

So I have:

The timer variable

```
this.timeOut = false;
```

These two functions, to enable the carousel or stop it:

```
stopSlide() {
    console.log('stop', this.timeOut);
    if (this.timeOut) {
        window.clearTimeout(this.timeOut);
        this.timeOut = null;
        delete this.timeOut;
    }
}

startSlide() {
    this.stopSlide();
    const hasMoreThanOneSlide = this.ribbon.querySelectorAll('.pts-desktop-header-ribbon__item').length > 1;
    this.timeOut = hasMoreThanOneSlide ? window.setTimeout(() => this.doPlay(this.play), this.time) : null;
    console.log('start', this.timeOut);
}
```

And this one that plays it (removing some index's vars and stuff so the question is not too large):

```
doPlay(element) {
    const newScroll = element.classList.contains(BUTTON_LEFT_CLASS) ? 1 : -1;
    const totalItems = this.el.querySelectorAll(`.${BASE_LIST_ITEM}`).length - 1;

    /* Update current */
    this.current++; // this wasn't like this cause actually i can turn +1 or -1 but I don't want to make this question longer

    /* Update visible */
    this.lists.forEach((list) => {
        list.style.transform = `translate(${-this.current * 100}%)`;
    });

    /* Update visible class */
    this.updateCurrentRibbonElement();
    if (this.timeOut) {
        this.stopSlide();
        this.startSlide();  // Calls the setTimeout function again
    } else {
        this.stopSlide();
    }
}
```

And this is how I init it:

```
events.delegate(this.el, `.${BUTTON_CLASS}`, 'click', (e) => {
    this.stopSlide();
    this.doPlay(e.elementTarget);
    this.hideRibbon();
});

/* Start interval */
this.startSlide();
```

Full class (in Webpack syntax) can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/toz4xafu/

So the problem is, that **Sometimes**, when using the arrows very fast ( stressing the app ) seems that is not clearing the `this.timeOut` var and it's multiple times executed ( instead of 7 seconds it's 2-4 seconds )

The question is, how can I make sure that I won't have more than one timeout running?

By the way, is there any way to debug how many timmers are executing?

Comment: Sorry, maybe i didn't express myself. By that I ment that using the directional arrows the timer should reset. So how would you adpat my `startSlide` and `stopSlide` functions?

Comment: @Shilly: but in that case, the timer could fire right after the click, which OP is probably trying to avoid.

Comment: @Shilly: when you say "cancelling the timeout with the buttons", you presumably mean clearing the interval and setting a new one inside the event handler?

Comment: I can't fix this to work as intended, my apologies.

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet: One detail though is strange (perhaps this is not your entire code): it looks like `doPlay` will never restart the timer after a click, since `stopSlide` is always called before `doPlay` inside the click handler. How is it at all possible that the timer would continue running after the first click? My suggestion would be to add a log inside the timer delegate, to be sure that you know where the call came from (i.e. `setTimeout(() => { console.log('timer fired'); this.doPlay(this.play); }, xxx);`).

Comment: @Groo I linked to the full class at the bottom of the question ^^

Comment: I see, it's a bit more complicated than the code in the question since `hideRibbon` and `showRibbon` also call `startSlide` and `stopSlide`, and they are called from other event handlers. Unless you want to rewrite everything, I would try to add logging to the timer callback to pinpoint the exact function which created the timer. A relatively easy way would be to add an incrementing counter inside `startSlide()` and write it to console with a stacktrace whenever `startSlide` is called. Then also capture the counter value inside the timer delegate and log it from there.

Comment: This would be a basic idea: http://jsfiddle.net/tb2nwuLh/, so that when the timer fires you know where exactly it came from.